# Joomla Community Builder Multiple Registration Forms

Tags: joomla2.5

I am new to Joomla. I have installed community builder plugin and created two different login pages and two register forms. Now I need to edit the login and register pages so that I can change the fields. Also I need to set two different usertypes for the two register forms submission.

Can any one help me out..

Any small help is most thanked in advance..

Cheers,
Radha

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of doing it
Download Community Builder 
http://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder

And then there is a plugin called CB Multi Registration
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/community-builder-extensions/community-builder-management/13451

Currently the plugin is not available for download. I am looking for it too. And an alternative way to acheive multiple registration forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by chronoform and cummunity builder

check this : http://back2dlab.com/tutorial/multi-page-forms-for-community-builder-joomla-registration

Answer (score 0):

Community Builder Profile Pro will be just what you need, it lets create CB profile types with different registration forms. Check it here http://www.joomduck.com/extensions/community-builder-profile-pro